# Pull from remote image unless build is explicitly called

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-build

Is there a way to have both `build:` and `image:` specified in a docker-compose yaml file and have them play nice?

Ideally, the remote image is pulled on `docker-compose up`, and are built instead when `docker-compose up --build` or `docker-compose build` are run. The issue is a bit of a nuisance when developers must comment out the build param to pull the remote image.

### Example 1

```
build: ./nginx
image: us.gcr.io/cool-project-123456/dev-box:latest
```

Build is *always* run, and then names and tags the container with the `image:` value.

### Example 2

```
# build: ./nginx
image: us.gcr.io/cool-project-123456/dev-box:latest
```

Here it seems that as long as `build:` is commented, and `image:` exists, all build commands are ignored and the image is pulled instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1 is not always run. It runs only when your don't have that image: `us.gcr.io/cool-project-123456/dev-box:latest`

`docker-compose up` is always using existing images in your machine first.

My suggestion is keeping

```
build: ./nginx
image: us.gcr.io/cool-project-123456/dev-box:latest
```

and using

- `docker-compose up --build`
- `docker-compose pull & docker-compose up`